# DNS Cache Poisoning

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle, dns, spoofing

I'm in a process of learning how to perform a DNS cache poisoning attack.
I run everything on an isolated VM environment, for educational purposes only.

The setup is a linux machine with `Unbound` DNS Server configured as a recursive resolver, which I try to poison.

For simplicity, I allow myself to be MITM (for in and out packets).
I use `dig` to query the resolver for a domain name, for example, `www.google.com`.

The resolver queries some DNS server for an answer.
Then, using scapy and python-nfqueue, I catch the final result packet, and change the answer so it will contain only an NS name `(ns1.google.com, sometimes ns2 etc)` as an NS record, and an additional record of `ns1.google.com` with an IP of `6.6.6.6`.

Here's a printscreen from Wireshark (of the final answer packet I modified):
[image]

And here's a proof that the cache is poisoned:
[image]

Now, I stop the poisoning script, and I expect that the next time I query a subdomain like `www.images.google.com`, the poisoned resolver would recognize `www.images.google.com` as a subdomain of `google.com`, thus will attempt to query `ns1.google.com` at `6.6.6.6` using the cached record.

However it is not happening, and the resolver attempts to query an outer DNS server instead using the cache.

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: have a look here https://forums.hak5.org/index.php?/topic/34839-sslstrip-not-working/

Comment: How you are so sure that google is vulnerable fr DNS cache poisoning? That might have already been patched.

Comment: What value are you setting for the TTL field?

Comment: I wonder if you query the poisoned DNS about images.google.com with "Recursion desired" bit disabled, will it return 6.6.6.6?